# Getting Monaco to work with Vuejs and electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, amd, monaco-editor

I'm interested in using the [Monaco](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) editor in a [Vue.js](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwisn-yUibLaAhVRnOAKHYPjA24QFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvuejs.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw06q0bfK8Y9QAOb2C8cD5Qh) backed [Electron](https://electronjs.org) project.

#### Thus far:

Microsoft provides an [Electron Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/tree/master/electron-amd) (which I've run and works correctly)

There are a variety of `vue.js` [npm repos](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=vue%20monaco) for monaco - yet none of them *seem* to fully support Electron right out of the box.

The one that looks most promising is [vue-monaco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-monaco) but I've run into issues correctly integrating it.

### AMD Require?

This is the code from the Microsoft sample for using with Electron

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Monaco Editor!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Monaco Editor in Electron!</h1>
        <div id="container" style="width:500px;height:300px;border:1px solid #ccc"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        // Monaco uses a custom amd loader that overrides node's require.
        // Keep a reference to node's require so we can restore it after executing the amd loader file.
        var nodeRequire = global.require;
    </script>
    <script src="../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Save Monaco's amd require and restore Node's require
        var amdRequire = global.require;
        global.require = nodeRequire;
    </script>

    <script>
        // require node modules before loader.js comes in
        var path = require('path');

        function uriFromPath(_path) {
            var pathName = path.resolve(_path).replace(/\\/g, '/');
            if (pathName.length > 0 && pathName.charAt(0) !== '/') {
                pathName = '/' + pathName;
            }
            return encodeURI('file://' + pathName);
        }

        amdRequire.config({
            baseUrl: uriFromPath(path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min'))
        });

        // workaround monaco-css not understanding the environment
        self.module = undefined;

        // workaround monaco-typescript not understanding the environment
        self.process.browser = true;

        amdRequire(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
            var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
                value: [
                    'function x() {',
                    '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
                    '}'
                ].join('\n'),
                language: 'javascript'
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

The module I'm using allows for something like this:

```
<template>
    <monaco-editor :require="amdRequire" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        amdRequire: window.amdRequire
        // Or put this in `data`, doesn't really matter I guess
    }
}
</script>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the correct `amdRequire` variable defined in Electon + vue.  I believe if i can conquer this everything else becomes simple.

The Electron FAQ mentions something about this (i think): [I can not sue jQuery/RequireJS/Meteor/AngularJS in Electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron)

### Sample Code

I put a sample project up on GitHub https://github.com/jeeftor/Vue-Monaco-Electron with the "offending" component being in [./src/renderer/components/Monaco.vue](https://github.com/jeeftor/Vue-Monaco-Electron/blob/master/src/renderer/components/Monaco.vue)

## Summary

**How can I get this Monaco Editor to load correctly inside of a Vue.js component that will be run inside electron?**

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm doing nearly the same, just without the extra vue-monaco component. After struggling quite a bit, I could solve the problem:

```
function loadMonacoEditor () {
  const nodeRequire = global.require

  const loaderScript = document.createElement('script')

  loaderScript.onload = () => {
    const amdRequire = global.require
    global.require = nodeRequire

    var path = require('path')

    function uriFromPath (_path) {
      var pathName = path.resolve(_path).replace(/\\/g, '/')

      if (pathName.length > 0 && pathName.charAt(0) !== '/') {
        pathName = '/' + pathName
      }

      return encodeURI('file://' + pathName)
    }

    amdRequire.config({
      baseUrl: uriFromPath(path.join(__dirname, '../../../node_modules/monaco-editor/min'))
    })

    // workaround monaco-css not understanding the environment
    self.module = undefined

    // workaround monaco-typescript not understanding the environment
    self.process.browser = true

    amdRequire(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
      this.monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
        value: [
          'function x() {',
          '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
          '}'
        ].join('\n'),
        language: 'javascript'
      })
    })
  }

  loaderScript.setAttribute('src', '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js')
  document.body.appendChild(loaderScript)
}
```

I've just taken the electron-amd sample and adjusted it a bit. I call the `loadMonacoEditor` function in the components' created function.

In order to not get the `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/.../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css` problem, you also have to set

```
webPreferences: {
  webSecurity: false
}
```

in your instance of the `BrowserWindow`.

Comment: Any chance you got a repo on GitHub for this?

Comment: Sure, have a look at this component in my repo: https://github.com/PapaMufflon/hugo-desktop/blob/master/src/renderer/components/Editor.vue